# Save Form recognize scanned data in Database table

Tags: forms, azure, azure-form-recognizer

After scanning my document with #AzureFormRecognizer[fott-preview.azurewebsites.net], How I store this field and data in oracle/MS server database. I see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle but couldn't understand those things. Please help me

[image: After scanning document in https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.   Your question is very broad and doesn't really explain what problems you are having, and most likely will be closed because of this.

Comment: write nore details.

Comment: It Microsoft Azure Form recognition API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form Recognizer output is a JSON output, you can use Logic App or Power Automate database connectors to take the JSON output into a database.